# How to run mpirun bw venv on two nodes

Tags: python-venv, mpi4py

I have to execute `mpirun` command on two python virtual environments between two separate nodes. I have named venv same along with path towards code file. My `machinefile` looks like this:

```
dell@192.168.0.29 max_slots=2 
dell@192.168.0.30 max_slots=1
```

where second entry is master node.

When I execute `mpirun` command from venv of master node, it failed saying `moduleNotFoundERROR` but package is already installed in venv of worker node. If I remove `machinefile`, command run successfully.

Is something else required in configurations while communicating with venvs?